# Extracting a string from a single column and adding strings before and after

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a text file with 2 space delimited strings (I like to view this a a file with 2 columns) and millions of lines.
I need to write the strings in column 2 and add a another string before and after the extracted string.
Example:
The original file looks like this:

```
id position
1 37474
2 4883
etc etc
```

I need to make another file which looks like this:

```
chr:37474-37474
chr:4883-4883
etc
```

i.e. write `chr:` and append the string in the second column from the original file, two times with "`-`" in-between.

I know how to extract the string from the second column in the original file and write it to a new file, but I'm not sure how to do what I'v shown above. Could anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` can be a way:

```
$ awk '{printf "chr:%s-%s\n",$2,$2}' file
chr:position-position
chr:37474-37474
chr:4883-4883
chr:etc-etc
```

- `{printf "chr:%s-%s\n",$2,$2}` prints "chr:" + the second field twice.

In case you don't need the first row, you can use `NR>1` before the `{}` block, so that it won't be processed.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/.* (.*)/chr:\1-\1/' file
```

or without `-r`:

```
sed 's/.* \(.*\)/chr:\1-\1/'
```

would do:

```
kent$  echo "1 37474
2 4883
etc etc"|sed -r 's/.* (.*)/chr:\1-\1/'
chr:37474-37474
chr:4883-4883
chr:etc-etc
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
awk 'NR>1 {print "chr:"$2"-"$2}' file
chr:37474-37474
chr:4883-4883
```

Answer (score 0):

The original file has the header, here is the solution:

Using awk

```
awk 'NR>1{printf "chr:%s-%s\n",$2,$2}' file
```

Using sed

```
sed -rn '/[0-9]/ s/.* (.*)/chr:\1-\1/p' file
```